# Bootstrap popover disappears immediately after second appearance

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-popover

I have a bootstrap popover with the following configuration/initialization:

```
$element.popover({trigger: 'manual'});
```

with

```
$element.data('bs.popover').options.content = 'some text';
$element.popover('show');
```

the popover will be triggered. but after the second appearance of the popover, it shows up for a second and disappears immediately. after that the popover element is destroyed.

after debugging bootstrap.js, i can say, that neither the "hide" nor the "destroy" action is triggered after the "show"-action.

**EDIT:**

okay, i fixed it... before one popover is shown, a "hideAll" method(this includes the popover which will have to be shown) was called. i guess the hide of one popover is called asynchronously by bootstrap, because of the fading out animation.

now i except the specific popover from the hideAll ... and all works fine

Comment: Why not just use native bootstrap instead of js? http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers

Comment: Because it is integrated in a knockout custombinding.

Comment: Can we get a working example in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/kcpma/) that recreates the exact problem you're having?

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue. I had a bunch of popovers in place to guide a user through filling out the inputs in a form.  My validation step would choose the next input that needed it's popover activated, hide all popovers and then show the one for the next input.  I liked the idea that I could ensure that only one popover was visible at a time by always hiding all `$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover("hide");` then showing one with `$('#' + current_popover_id).popover("show");`.  The asynchronous nature what not as consistent as I hoped.  I ended up hiding one popover and showing one popover at a time.